# Chromecast SDK 3.0, Custom Receiver, Volume

Tags: android, chromecast, volume, google-cast

Have migrated from cast sdk2 to 3 but now not sure how to handle cast volume with a custom receiver. Can send messages to adjust the receiver volume ok by catching hardware volume key events, but this occurs without visual volume slider feedback on the sender. If I don't catch events and don't send messages the hardware volume buttons just control the ringer volume (with visual feedback). Anyone figured this out?

Comment: Could you try the CastVideos-android sample and see if that works fine?

Comment: Thanks Ali. I have that project built. Seems you have to go all in with the mini and expanded cast controllers to get this to work... at least that's my guess.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. The volume management on a cast devices is done through the MediaSessionCompat and that is independent of the mini-controller or the expanded controller. As a test, disable the mini-controller and expanded controller in the CastVideso-android sample and try again.

Comment: Thanks again Ali - let me take a look at the MediaSession stuff

Comment: Not really finding any suitable examples of MediaSessionCompat and Cast SDK 3. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Cast SDK internally uses MediaSessionCompat; if you look at CCL, a similar treatment is happening.

Comment: My custom receiver implements a YouTube player in an iframe and all communication is through custom messaging. Looking through the Cast SDK 3 receiver documentation there is the creation of a cast.receiver.MediaManager instance which I haven't used before. If I copy some of the CastVideos-android code (RemoteMediaClient.load/play etc) and load one of the videos and add the cast.receiver.MediaManager to my receiver then the test video plays and the volume controls work. So I guess the question is, without the need to use RemoteMediaClient, how do I control cast volume on the sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a truely custom receiver, create a cast.receiver.media.Player object on the receiver (implement all the cast.receiver.media.Player functions) and pass it to the instance of cast.receiver.MediaManager. From the sender, bind to this with CastSession.getRemoteMediaClient(). Now call RemoteMediaClient.load/play in addition to my custom messaging load/plays and this fools the sender into behaving correctly. Now the cast framework controls volume, notifications etc as with the CastVideos-android app. You'll also have to have the receiver provide the necessary state on the server in the cast.receiver.media.Player.getState() function (ie. return "PLAYING | "PAUSED" | "IDLE" | "BUFFERING")